# Assigning ID to each line by column value in awk

Tags: awk

I have a tabular file with a column that is recurrent example

```
toto tata AFG
fff ddd AFG
ff hhh AWM
qqq ttt AWM
```

I would like to have an output like

```
toto tata AFG 1
fff ddd AFG 1
ff hhh AWM 2
qqq ttt AWM 2
```

by comparing each line to the next one using the 4th column

Is it possible to do it fast with awk ?

thx for help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
awk '$3 != current {id++; current=$3} {print $0, id}'
```

Answer (score 1):

Put input in a file.

```
$> cat ./text
toto tata AFG
fff ddd AFG
ff hhh AWM
qqq ttt AWM
```

For each line we should remember $3-st value and check if it is equal to the previous one. If it is true - we should increment the iterator.

```
awk '
BEGIN {
    prevValue = "";
    value = "";
    iterator = 0;
}
{
    prevValue = value;
    value = $3;
    if (value != prevValue)
        iterator++;
    printf $0 " " iterator "\n"
}' ./text
```

So what we get is this

```
toto tata AFG 1
fff ddd AFG 1
ff hhh AWM 2
qqq ttt AWM 2
```

**UPD**:
Like Jonathan Leffler said initial section is not really necessary here. So another workable solution is:

```
awk '
{
    prevValue = value
    value = $3
    if (value != prevValue)
        iterator++
    print $0, iterator
}' ./text
```

Comment: +1: This is rather verbose; the initialization section can be assumed (you are doing explicitly what `awk` does implicitly).